# Transposing lists in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to transpose a list of lists; my comments indicate the thought process.

```
(setq thingie  '((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9)))  ;;test case

(defun trans (mat)
  (if (car mat)
    (let ((top (mapcar 'car  mat))   ;;slice the first row off as a list
          (bottom (mapcar 'cdr mat))) ;;take the rest of the rows
      (cons top (trans bottom))))    ;;cons the first-row-list with the next-row-list
   mat)

(trans thingie)
=> ((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9))           ;;wait what?
```

But, I really want it to be

```
((1 4 7) (2 5 8) (3 6 9))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is called [matrix transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose).

Comment: @sds: ... yuuup. Why I didn't see that 3 years ago is beyond me. Give me a few minutes and I'll fix this up.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is a simple way for this:

```
(defun rotate (list-of-lists)
  (apply #'mapcar #'list list-of-lists))
```

Your attempt is always returning the original `mat`.  Fix your indentation, and you see that the returned value from the `if` form is always thrown away.

*Edit:*  How this works:

- `List` takes any number of arguments and makes a list of it.  Its function definition can be imagined about like this:

  ```
  (defun list (&rest arguments)
    arguments) ; exploit the automatic &rest construction
  ```
- `Mapcar` takes a function and any number of lists, and then makes a
  new list of the values created by calling the function always with
  one element from those lists.  Example: `(mapcar #'foo '((A B) (C
  D)))` will construct a new list, where the first element is the
  result of `(foo 'A 'C)` and the second the result of `(foo 'B 'D)`.
- `Apply` takes a spreadable argument list designator as its last
  argument.  This means that if you give it a list as its last
  argument, that list can be "spread" to produce individual arguments
  for the function.  Example: `(apply #'+ '(1 2 3))` has the same
  effect as `(+ 1 2 3)`.

Now you can expand the line:

```
(apply #'mapcar #'list '((A B) (C D)))
```

=>

```
(mapcar #'list '(A B) '(C D))
```

=>

```
(list (list 'A 'C) (list 'B 'D))
```

=>

```
'((A C) (B D))
```

Comment: Hnnng. Can you elucidate a little more on the reasoning for your rotate? I don't quite see *how* it generates the solution.

Comment: There's a problem with some degenerate cases. Try `(rotate nil)` or `(rotate '(nil))`