# passing function output as another function argument for matrix transpose in lisp

Tags: matrix, lisp, arguments, output

I'm in the process of writing a matrix transpose function in lisp. My approach can be seen from the following code:

```
(defun matrix-T (matrix)
  (cond ((null matrix) matrix)
        (t (list
            (do ((i 0 (+ i 1)))
                ((> i (length matrix)))
              (format t "(mapcar #'(lambda (x)(nth ~A x)) matrix)  %" i))))))
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get the output from the do loop to pass as an 
argument for the list function. However, I only get the do loop output returned from matrix-T. Is there anyway I can rectify this?

Comment: Your DO loop doesn't have anything in the return-value subform, so it returns NIL.  It just prints output to `*STANDARD-OUTPUT*` with the FORMAT function. What do you want to return?

Comment: I just wanted it to return the text it outputs

Comment: But output is not the same thing as return value. Do you really want `matrix-T` to return a list of strings rather than a new matrix?

Comment: The concept was to enter the output into the list function as an argument, and then a new matrix would be returned.

Comment: I'm representing matrices as lists in lists.

Comment: Ok, I'll replace that section with a function that will return the text

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swapping rows and columns in common lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513128/swapping-rows-and-columns-in-common-lisp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dead-simple straight forward way to transpose a matrix:

```
(defun transpose-matrix (matrix)
  (let ((result
         (make-array (reverse (array-dimensions matrix))
                     :element-type (array-element-type matrix))))
    (dotimes (i (array-dimension result 0) result)
      (dotimes (j (array-dimension result 1))
        (setf (aref result i j) (aref matrix j i))))))

(print
 (transpose-matrix
  #2A((1 2 3)
      (4 5 6))))
;; #2A((1 4) (2 5) (3 6))
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I used lists because they seem more flexible but this is just as quick.

Comment: @Bracket: for lists, you can use the apply mapcar list thing shown in another answer.  It is, however, often more natural and performant to represent matrices as arrays in Common Lisp, because it has real multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually run the MAPCAR and collect its results in a list, not just print or return it as a string.

```
(defun matrix-T (matrix)
  (cond ((null matrix) matrix)
        (t (do ((i 0 (1+ i))
                (result '())
                (cols (length (car matrix))))
               ((>= i cols) (nreverse result))
             (push (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (nth i x)) matrix) result)))))
```

Comment: Thanks very much- may I ask, why does the do iterator only return the completed result list?

Comment: It returns whatever you tell it to return. The body is just for performing actions. If you want an iteration macro that automatically gathers data into a return list, use `loop` with its `collect` operation.

Comment: I meant why doesn't it return the steps up to the completed list, just the end result?

Comment: Because the steps are often just intermediate values, not things you want to return. You get to control what you want returned and what shouldn't. Consider if the step was an `if` statement, where you wanted to choose whether to return that row or not.

Comment: Is that control expressed in (nreverse result) ?

Comment: No, the control is expressed in `(push ... result)`. You could have something like `(if <whatever> (push ... result))`, so that it would only add return the pieces that satisfy the check.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way to transpose using mapcar*

```
(defun transpose-matrix (matrix)
  (apply #'mapcar* #'list matrix))

(transpose-matrix '(("1" "a" "e") ("2" "b" "f") ("4" "c" "g") ("5" "d" "h")))

(("1" "2" "4" "5") ("a" "b" "c" "d") ("e" "f" "g" "h"))
```

Comment: What is `mapcar*`, and how is it different from `mapcar`?  Other than that, this is really a simple way to do this with lists.

Comment: mapcar* is an alias in emacslisp for `cl-mapcar` cl-mapcar is a compiled Lisp function in ‘cl-lib.el’.

(cl-mapcar FUNCTION SEQ...)

Apply FUNCTION to each element of SEQ, and make a list of the results.
If there are several SEQs, FUNCTION is called with that many arguments,
and mapping stops as soon as the shortest list runs out.  With just one
SEQ, this is like ‘mapcar’.  With several, it is like the Common Lisp
‘mapcar’ function extended to arbitrary sequence types.