# Rotate a List of Lists

Tags: list, racket

I want to take an arbitrary list of lists and "rotate" it.  That is, for a list of lists of size 3x3:

```
#lang racket
(require rackunit)

(define (rotate-lol lol)
  (append (list (map first lol)) (list (map second lol)) (list (map third lol))))

(check-equal? (rotate-lol (list (list 'a 'b 'c)
                                (list 'd 'e 'f)
                                (list 'g 'h 'i)))
          (list (list 'a 'd 'g)
                (list 'b 'e 'h)
                (list 'c 'f 'i)))
```

I'm thinking `list-ref` will replace `first`/`second`/`third` but I can't quite figure out the most concise way to do this.

I *know* there has got to be an elegant way to do this.  I've done somewhat inelegant solutions to this problem in the past that were more domain specific, but I'd like to solve this for the general case, stash this in a personal library, and be done with the problem. Any tips or solutions?

Comment: This is typically called a matrix transpose.  E.g., see [Transposing lists in Common Lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3513128/1281433).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I knew there was a better way to state it.  That's why I put "rotate" in quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty much like `zip` and you don't have to make it since it's already in the [SRFI-1 list library](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html):

```scm
(require srfi/1)
(zip '(a b c) '(d e f) '(g h I)) ; ==> ((a d g) (b e h) (c f i))
```

Now to get to take all parameters as a list you use apply:

```scm
(apply zip '((a b c) (d e f) (g h I)))
; ==> ((a d g) (b e h) (c f i))
```

And, just for completeness. Here is how `zip` is defined:

```scm
(define (zip . lsts)
  (apply map list lsts))
```

Comment: That's funny.  I implemented zip myself in another setting and used it to solve a very similar problem.  For some reason it is `apply` that always eludes my thought processes... Thank you!